# Find maximum rating from PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, pyspark

I have a Dataframe (`pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame`)`user_recs` of type `DataFrame[user: int, recommendations: array<struct<item:int,rating:float>>]`.

I want to select for every user the best `rating` and its corresponding `item`.

For example, for user number `471` I have the following row

```
user_recs.where(user_recs.user == 471).select("recommendations.item", "recommendations.rating").collect()
>>>[Row(item=[0, 23, 4], rating=[0.005226806737482548, 0.0044402251951396465, 0.004139747936278582])]
```

I want the result to be a Dataframe similar to `user_recs` but with maximum rating. I want `item` number to be 0 since it has best rating of 0.005*. (Rating also to be included in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to use Spark's `map` method and sort to get the top rating per user. It would look something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def top_rating(s):
    return sorted(s, lambda x: x.rating)[0]

top_rating_udf = udf(top_rating)
result = user_recs.withColumn('top_rated_item', top_rating_udf(col('recommendations'))
```

I haven't test it, but that should be close. Notice, this actually gives you a new column with the result, so you don't have to drop the other columns if you don't want. You could also extract the top rating and the top item in their own columns:

```
result.select('user', 'top_rated_item.item', 'top_rated_item.rating')
```

Comment: I am getting this error `AssertionError: col should be Column` for `result`

Comment: You'll want something like: `col('top_rated_item')`, sorry.

Comment: Actually, I had that backwards, it was because I was passing the function `top_rating_udf`, but not giving it any input column. I just edited my answer to fix this.

Comment: For the line: `result.select('user', 'top_rated_item.item', 'top_rated_item.rating')` Rating is not of type struct: `Can't extract value from top_rated_item#19022: need struct type but got string;`

Comment: Does the new column `top_rated_item` look right  in `result`? I just want to make sure before we troubleshoot the select.

Comment: Can you give an example by which I can look `top_rated_item` in `result`

Comment: Have you tried `result.select('top_rated_item').show(false)`? What does it say?

Comment: `result.select(col_name).show()` provides output for `user` and `recommendation.item` and `recommendation.rating`  **but not** for `top_rated_item`